# Update Uniform.js input not working

Tags: javascript, uniform

I'm using `Uniform.js` on all `selects`, `input:checkbox`, `input:text` elements.

The problem I'm running into is that the actual values of the elements that are using Uniform are not updating.  I have a form containing these various elements, I change their values, and then call `$.uniform.update()` before the form is submitted (I've also tried updating individual elements), but the element value is not actually changed.

For example, if I have a select w/ the options Yes and No, if I select Yes the only thing that is changed is the span that is generated by Uniform.  So when I the form is submitted I get no value.

(using jquery 1.6.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for `load()` if fix promblem this way:

```
$('#dialog').load(url + ' #forload', 
    function() {
        $('#dialog').find('select').uniform(), $('#dialog').find('input:checkbox').uniform()
    })
```